# Dynamically replace flexipage record Id based on Org

Tags: salesforcedx, flexipages

we have a Flexipage page metadata which has record Ids derived from a managed package attached to it. Now when we commit this to our repository, that record Id is saved in branch. However, if we go deploy this to different org, the validation job fails because the record Id is different in another org

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlexiPage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <!-- Other metadata item here -->
    <itemInstances>
        <componentInstance>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>selectedCollectionId</name>
                <value>a1123abbbbbb15IbABC</value> <!-- I want to change this value here. Record Ids differ per branch (DEV QA UAT) -->
            </componentInstanceProperties>
        <itemInstances>
    <componentInstance>
</FlexiPage>
```

Is there any feature in SFDX that allows us to change this value per org?

Thank you